# Creating a Flutter Web sidebar with expandable tiles

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter Web project and I'm trying to implement a sidebar that has expandable tiles, similar to what you would see on many websites. The sidebar should initially show just icons on the left, and when an icon is clicked, a list of expandable tiles should appear below it.

I'd like the sidebar to have the following features:

- Initially show only icons.
- When an icon is clicked, a list of expandable tiles should be revealed below it.
- Clicking on a tile should expand it to reveal more content, and clicking again should collapse it.

I've tried using packages like SidebarX and collapsible_sidebar, and I've also attempted to build my own sidebar from scratch. However, I'm struggling to achieve the desired behavior of having expandable tiles that can be collapsed again.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you an example here. Research a little bit and customize it yourself.

Create a `class` for SidebarItems and subItems.

```
class SidebarItem {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final List<String> expandableTiles;

  SidebarItem(
      {required this.title, required this.icon, required this.expandableTiles});
}

List<SidebarItem> sidebarItems = [
  SidebarItem(
    title: 'Home',
    icon: Icons.home,
    expandableTiles: ['Subitem 1', 'Subitem 2'],
  ),
  SidebarItem(
    title: 'Settings',
    icon: Icons.settings,
    expandableTiles: ['Subitem 1', 'Subitem 2'],
  ),
  // Add more items if you need
];
```

//Creating Sidebar class here

```
class Sidebar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sidebar({super.key});

  @override
  _SidebarState createState() => _SidebarState();
}

class _SidebarState extends State<Sidebar> {
  int _selectedItemIndex = -1; // 0 will be selected 1st item

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: sidebarItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        bool isSelected = _selectedItemIndex == index;

        return Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(sidebarItems[index].icon),
              trailing: Icon(isSelected
                  ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                  : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              title: Text(sidebarItems[index].title),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedItemIndex = isSelected ? -1 : index;
                });
              },
            ),
            if (isSelected)
              Column(
                children: sidebarItems[index].expandableTiles.map((tile) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(tile),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            const Divider(), // divider between items
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Implement your sideBar here

```
class ImplementSideBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImplementSideBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(
        child: Sidebar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The final result will be look like -

[image]